# How to Make Retrofit-Rest Api call from Android Fragment?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, retrofit2, navigation-drawer

I am trying to make a Rest call using Retrofit from inside the onCreateView method of the Fragment Class and pass the result obtained to a recycler view.

The problem that I am facing is that the Blank Fragment UI gets created without the Recycler View and the List data from the Rest call.

Below is the code that I am using in the Fragment along with the Rest Call.The fragments are controlled from the Navigation Drawer which is a part of the MainActivity from where I am making transaction to different Fragments.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
shopDetailsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
shopDetailsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
shopDetailsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
Paper.init(getContext());
CustomerAddressDetail customerAddressDetail = Paper.book().read("customerAddressDetail", new 
CustomerAddressDetail());

Retrofit retrofit = CustomerConnectionLayer.getClient();
ShopDetailService shopDetailService = retrofit.create(ShopDetailService.class);
Call<List<ShopAddressDetail>> shopDetailsPincode = shopDetailService.getShopDetailsPincode(customerAddressDetail.getPincode());
shopDetailsPincode.enqueue(new Callback<List<ShopAddressDetail>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<ShopAddressDetail>> call, Response<List<ShopAddressDetail>> response) {
        List<ShopAddressDetail> shopList = response.body();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(shopList)) {
            shopDetailsList = shopList;
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Service Not Available at Current Pincode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<ShopAddressDetail>> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
adapter = new ShopDetailsBindingAdapter(shopDetailsList, getActivity());
shopDetailsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the RecyclerView inside the `onResponse` of the retrofit call. These lines
`adapter = new ShopDetailsBindingAdapter(shopDetailsList, getActivity());
shopDetailsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`
should be in the `onResponse` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since your request does not block the main thread, shopDetailsList is bound to the RecyclerView before your network response is received. You can either wait to set the adapter until the response is received as Beast77 suggested, or notify the adapter when the data has changed.

Try putting this line in `onResponse` after `shopDetailsList = shopList`:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will let the adapter know that `shopDetailsList` has changed, and the RecyclerView will rebind to the updated data.